# Kentico Phone Format not consistent

Tags: forms, formatting, kentico

I'm adding a US phone number to a form in Kentico 9 but the format is not consistent. When I create my form in the Form Builder it looks like this:

[Well Formatted US phone format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiTAg.png)

However when I view the form it Kentico splits up the phone number into it's component parts and places them all on one line. I'm not finding a place to fix this. Seems like a silly way to work...

[Bad Phone image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3YWj.png)

I've tried creating Custom Layouts but it doesn't appear to allow you to control the format there.

Comment: This seems to be CSS issue. Check you styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you right  - you have a form with field (Data type: text) which is using *U.S. phone number* form control. You can specify proper behavior in *~/CMSFormControls/Inputs/USphone.ascx* (default path where are files for this form control). You can specify css classes in *USphone.ascx* and general behavior in *USphone.ascx.cs* file. Please note this property:

```
public override object Value
{
    get
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }

        return String.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}", txt1st.Text, txt2nd.Text, txt3rd.Text);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

In return there is specified way you are formatting text - this might help you to achieve your desired behavior.